# Change char name containing colon (":") with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, kaggle

I have a dataset containing Country names written like this:

```
 - en:france
 - en:united-kingdom
 - en:spain
```

I would like to change the name into something like:

```
 - France
 - United_Kingdom
 - Spain
```

but if I use `select` function with `dplyr` I get this error:

> "Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'en' not found".

This is the code I've written so far (using a Data Frame from [Kaggle called foodfacts](https://www.kaggle.com/openfoodfacts/world-food-facts)):

```
countries <- foodfacts %>%
         tbl_df() %>%
         group_by(countries_tags) %>%
         summarise(count = n()) %>%
         filter(!grepl(",", countries_tags)) %>%
         select(France = en:france) %>%
         arrange(desc(count))
```

Can someone tell me how to change the name of an object containing colon?

Comment: Maybe `make.names(sub("en:", "", c("en:france","en:united-kingdom","en:spain")))` ? Also, error says `en:france` should be in quotes: `"en:france"`

Comment: Why not just use existing `foodfacts$countries_en` column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`select` only selects columns. In case the column name has a colon, you may have to use `select_` and quote the column name: `select_("en:france")`

If you need cases, you have to use `filter` - but note, that comparison need `==`, not a sinlge `=` (as in your select-call above): `filter(France == "en:france")`

If you need to rename **columns**, use `colnames(dat)[which(colnames(dat) == "en:france")] <- "France"`

If you need to rename **values**, you can also use `dat$x[which(dat$x == "en:france")] <- "France"`.

Comment: `dat$x[which(dat$x == "en:france")] <- "France"` that worked, thank you so much! ;)